# How to convert incomplete date to Date format?

Tags: r, date, datetime, datetime-format

How to convert the below in character to Date format?

```
YYYY.MM
```

I am facing an issue dealing with zeroes after decimal points for month 10.
Say

```
2012.10
```

appears in my input source data as

```
2012.1
```

with the zero post decimal missing. How do I bring this back in the Date format?

Comment: try running options(digits=2) is there still only one decimal place?

Comment: You need a _year_ and a _month_ and a _day_ for a date.  Otherwise there is a `yearmon` type.

Comment: How do you know whether 2012.1 means month 1 or month 10 if it is dropping trailing zeros?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck 2012.01 are January month related and 2012.1 are October related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have only `year` and `month`, you need to assign some value for `day` before you convert to date. In the example below, the day has arbitrarily been chosen as `15`.

**IF THE INPUT IS CHARACTER**

```
dates = c("2012.10", "2012.01")

lubridate::ymd(paste0(year_month = dates, day = "15"))
#[1] "2012-10-15" "2012-01-15"
```

**IF THE INPUT IS NUMERIC**

```
dates = c(2012.10, 2012.01)

do.call(c, lapply(strsplit(as.character(dates), "\\."), function(d){
    if(nchar(d[2]) == 1){
        d[2] = paste0(d[2],"0")
    }
    lubridate::ymd(paste0(year = d[1], month = d[2], day = "15"))
}))
#[1] "2012-10-15" "2012-01-15"
```

Comment: If the input is numeric, the conversion can be simplified to `lubridate::ymd(sprintf("%.2f-15", dates))`.

Answer (score 3):

The zoo package has a `"yearmon"` class for representing year and month without day.  Internally it stores them as year + fraction where fraction = 0 for Jan, 1/12 for Feb, 2/12 for Mar and so on but it prints in a nicer format and sorts as expected.  Assuming that your input, `x`, is numeric convert it to character with 2 digit month and then apply `as.yearmon` with the appropriate format.

```
library(zoo)

x <- c(2012.1, 2012.01)  # test data

as.yearmon(sprintf("%.2f", x), "%Y.%m")
## [1] "Oct 2012" "Jan 2012"
```

`as.Date` can be applied to convert a `"yearmon"` object to `"Date"` class if desired but normally that is not necessary.

```
as.Date(as.yearmon(sprintf("%.2f", x), "%Y.%m"))
## [1] "2012-10-01" "2012-01-01"
```

Answer (score 2):

The code below uses the `ymd()` function from the `lubridate` package and `sprintf()` to coerce dates given in a numeric format

```
dates <- c(2012.1, 2012.01)
```

as well as dates given as a character string

```
dates <- c("2012.1", "2012.01")
```

where the part left of the decimal point specifies the year whereas the fractional part denote the month.

```
lubridate::ymd(sprintf("%.2f", as.numeric(dates)), truncated = 1L)
```

> ```
> [1] "2012-10-01" "2012-01-01"
> ```

The format specification `%.2f` tells `sprintf()` to use 2 decimal places.

The parameter `truncated = 1L` indicates that one date element is missing (*day*) and should be completed by the default value (the first day of the month). Alternatively, the day of the month can be directly specified in the format specification to `sprintf()`:

```
lubridate::ymd(sprintf("%.2f-15", as.numeric(dates)))
```

> ```
> [1] "2012-10-15" "2012-01-15"
> ```