# Converting character to date R

Tags: r, date, format, date-conversion

I am running into some date issues when working with Dates in R.

Here's my situation.

I'm working on a dataset with a column date (ProjectDate) having the following values

```
class(Dataset$ProjectDate)
"character"

head(Dataset$ProjectDate)
"End July 2014" "End August 2014" "End September 2014" "End October 2014"
```

I would like to convert it to "%M %Y" format

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572818/unable-to-convert-month-year-string-to-date-in-r

Comment: and: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710362/how-to-convert-character-to-date-format-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think of using 2 step process. First remove the `End` part from the `ProjectDate` using `sub`.

Now you can apply `yearmon` from `zoo` library to convert to `month year` date format.

```
library(zoo)

as.yearmon(sub("^End ", "", df$ProjectDate), "%b %Y")
#[1] "Aug 2014" "Sep 2014"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.
First, the data.

```
x <- scan(what = character(),
          text = '"End July 2014" "End August 2014"
                  "End September 2014" "End October 2014"')
```

Now the conversion to dates. Note that your dates do not have a day, so I replace `"End"` by day `"1"`.

```
as.Date(sub("^[[:alpha:]]+", "1", x), "%d %B %Y")
#[1] "2014-07-01" "2014-08-01" "2014-09-01" "2014-10-01"
```